# implement a matrix in java

Tags: java, data-structures, matrix

hi i try to implement a matrix by java ... i want to write a method that it's argument is the row and the column of matrix and the method make the matrix.
i write this code but it have error .... what is my problem? please help me

```
public class Table {
int row ;
int column ;

Table (int rows , int columns ){
    row = rows;
    column = columns;
}

void makeTable(int row , int column){
    char[][] ;
    c.length = column ;
    c[0].length = row ;

}
}
```

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such

Comment: This one doesn't compile: char[][] ; . Did you miss a `c` there?

Comment: please submit either compiling code with a specific error, or provide the error in question; also, tag as homework.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Table {

    int row;
    int column;
    char[][] c;

    Table(int rows, int columns) {
        row = rows;
        column = columns;
        makeTable(rows, column);//calling initilizer method
    }

    private void makeTable(int row, int column) {
        c = new char[row][column];//initilizing c

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a specific error, but here are a few in your existing code:

```
void makeTable(int row , int column){
    // the next line is invalid - needs a variable name for the declaration
    char[][] ;
    // array length is not set as below, but is set at definition time
    c.length = column ;
    c[0].length = row ;

}
```

The correct way to define a multidimensional array in Java is:

```
char[][] c = new char[row][column];
```

You can also declare an array with ragged rows each of whom has a different column length (or the same, in your case, but why complicate things?) as follows:

```
char[][] c = new char[row][];
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    c[row] = new char[column];
}
```

Comment: Would a ragged array (i.e., an array of arrays of uneven length) not violate the definition of a matrix?

Comment: Not if you understand what you've done and can safely assume that all entries beyond the ragged end equal zero.  But if you do any operations with another matrix you'll have to treat that properly to get the right result.

Comment: what you mean ? can you explain?

Comment: @Rojin - which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered providing variable names? Or even declaring the matrix?

Imagine:

```
class Table {
char matrix[][];
public Table(int row, int column) {
    matrix=makeTable(row, column);
} 

char[][] makeTable(int row, int column) {
   return new char[row][column];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as storing the dimensions of the matrix (number of rows and columns) you require an array or similar structure to store the contents of the array. This would be a the class level (a member variable), `char[][] ;` you have in `makeTable()` is the wrong place to store that, and this won't build anyway because you haven't specified a name.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably homework and thus you're required to roll your own matrix class. But for others out there Apache Commons has a matrix library in their Math package that works very well.

http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/math/linear/RealMatrix.html